# Start command, force to open NOT AS ADMINISTRATOR

Tags: batch-file, cmd

If the batch file is opened as normal, "start" will obviously open the file as non-administrator.

If the batch file is opened as administrator, "start" will open the file as administrator.

This is troublesome because it needs to do two things:

1. taskkill, which requires administrator.
2. Opening FiveM, which requires not as Administrator.

Comment: Whilst we could guess what your question is, it is not really our place to do so; please [edit] your submission to clarify that question. Please also take a look at the built-in runas utility, and then create and post a [mcve] of your code. We're here to help you to fix an issue with your code, not to tell you how to code it, or code it for you.

Comment: I second @Compo. This question should be asked in https://superuser.com/ or other boards. This does not relate at all to development.

Answer (score 0):

... and why would `taskkill` need to be run as administrator?

```
Prompt>taskkill /PID 99999
ERROR: The process "99999" not found.
```

And this while I'm not logged as administrator.

What's that `FiveM` you're talking about? In case you're talking about the Grand Theft Auto client, there should not be any problem stopping this, using `taskkill` without being administrator.

Comment: You cannot kill a task if you do not have the required privileges. It is my assumption, based upon the question asked, that the user running the `taskkill` command falls into that category. The OP therefore assumes that running the taskkill.exe utility with elevation, or as another user with the required privileges, would cater for such a scenario.

Comment: That's exactly my point: administrator rights are not needed for opening `taskkill`, but the task https://stackoverflow.com/users/16385932/eyal282 wants to kill might. Rests the question: why would you need administrator priviledges for killing a task if this is to be followed by the startup of a task, for which no administrator rights are needed?

Comment: Dominique, based upon what was submitted, there needs to be no correlation between the two 'tasks'. Lets take a scenario; ProcessX started under the context of UserA, performs some sort of monitoring. UserB simply wishes to run ProcessY, under their own user context, without being monitored or inconvenienced by ProcessX. They therefore need to stop or pause ProcessX, with elevated/higher permissions, in order for ProcessY to work as needed with their normal permissions.